# chown not working when coping a file in a dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, elasticsearch, dockerfile

I'm running docker engine on windows and am trying to add my own file to the image. Problem is that when I copy the file its ownership is always root:root but it needs to be heartbeat:heartbeat (exisitng user on image). Mounting a single file with the -v parameter und docker run doesn't seam to be possible on windows atm. Thats why I tried to create my own image with a docker file:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/beats/heartbeat:7.16.3
USER root
COPY --chown=heartbeat:heartbeat yml/heartbeat.yml /usr/share/heartbeat/heartbeat.yml
RUN chown -R heartbeat:heartbeat /usr/share/heartbeat
```

The --chown parameter behind the coping does nothing. It is still root when I check and the RUN chown command results in a error. Here the output:

```
docker image build ./ -t custom/heartbeat:7.16.3
Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.75kB
Step 1/4 : FROM docker.elastic.co/beats/heartbeat:7.16.3
 ---> b64ad4b42006
Step 2/4 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 922a9121e51b
Step 3/4 : COPY --chown=heartbeat:heartbeat yml/heartbeat.yml /usr/share/heartbeat/heartbeat.yml
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f30eb4934dca
Step 4/4 : RUN chown -R heartbeat:heartbeat /usr/share/heartbeat
 ---> [Warning] The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (windows/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
 ---> Running in 2ae3bfdd5422
The command '/bin/sh -c chown -R heartbeat:heartbeat /usr/share/heartbeat' returned a non-zero code: 4294967295: failed to shutdown container: container 2ae3bfdd5422e81461a14896db0908e4cd67af1a6f99c629abff1e588f62fc32 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110): subsequent terminate failed container 2ae3bfdd5422e81461a14896db0908e4cd67af1a6f99c629abff1e588f62fc32 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110)
```

All help is welcome...

Running with --platform:

```html
PS C:\SynteticMonitoring> docker image build ./ -t custom/heartbeat:7.16.3
Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.728kB
Step 1/4 : FROM --platform=linux/amd64 docker.elastic.co/beats/heartbeat:7.16.3
 ---> b64ad4b42006
Step 2/4 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 922a9121e51b
Step 3/4 : COPY --chown=heartbeat:heartbeat yml/heartbeat.yml /usr/share/heartbeat/heartbeat.yml
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f30eb4934dca
Step 4/4 : RUN chmod +r /usr/share/heartbeat/heartbeat.yml
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e9a075d2ab53
Successfully built e9a075d2ab53
Successfully tagged custom/heartbeat:7.16.3
PS C:\SynteticMonitoring> docker run --interactive --tty --entrypoint /bin/sh custom/heartbeat:7.16.3
sh-4.2# ls -l
total 106916
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     13675 Jan  7 00:47 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1964303 Jan  7 00:47 NOTICE.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       851 Jan  7 00:47 README.md
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root      4096 Jan  7 00:48 data
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    374197 Jan  7 00:47 fields.yml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 107027952 Jan  7 00:47 heartbeat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     69196 Jan  7 00:47 heartbeat.reference.yml
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root      1631 Jan 26 06:49 heartbeat.yml
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Jan  7 00:47 kibana
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root      4096 Jan  7 00:48 logs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Jan  7 00:47 monitors.d
sh-4.2# pwd
/usr/share/heartbeat
```

Comment: which version of docker do you use? Flag `--chown` was added in version 17.09

Comment: Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        40ef3b6
 Built:             08/19/2021 18:54:26
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Comment: For what it's worth, I've tried recreating and haven't succeeded on Linux. Your Dockerfile should be right, even without the `chown -R`. Best guess is if it has to do with the Windows filesystem, perhaps mapping the ownership since you are running the container as root.

Comment: Can you click on the docker icon in the tray and switch into Linux containers, and try again ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `chown` of a file to a user that does not exist. It seems that the `heartbeat` user and group do not exist in your base image.

That's why the `COPY --chown` does nothing and you get files owned by `root`.

You can fix this by creating the user before `COPY`ing. To do this, add a line before your `COPY` statement, such as:

```
RUN addgroup heartbeat && adduser -S -H heartbeat -G heartbeat
```

If you don't have `addgroup` and `adduser` in your base image, try alternative:

```
RUN useradd -rUM -s /usr/sbin/nologin heartbeat
```

This will create the group and user `heartbeat` and then `chown` will be able to successfully change the ownership.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from):

> The optional `--platform` flag can be used to specify the platform of the image in case `FROM` references a multi-platform image. For example, `linux/amd64`, `linux/arm64`, or `windows/amd64`. *By default, the target platform of the build request is used*.

I suggest try something like:

```
FROM [--platform=<platform>] <image> [AS <name>]
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 docker.elastic.co/beats/heartbeat:7.16.3
```

Comment: Thank you for the tipp. Unfortunately I still have the problem